# CSS - Manage page break in case of printing

Tags: css, page-break

I made a generator of trombinoscope for my wife (school teacher).
She can upload many pictures of students, resize/crop and check some options to display information (like first name / last name for exemple)

At screen, everything is ok. I use a classic bootstrap, so responsive is correctly applied on all elements.
See the screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

When i call my print function (classic javascript window.print()), i have a minor issue of page break.

[image: Screenshot2]

In my css file, i use tag "@media screen" to apply design only in case of desktop.
In case of print, there is no rule applied to elements.

I attached a little part of code

[image]

I think that the fix is a CSS tag like page-break-after or page-break-before, but i don't know where apply it...
Could you help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css instruction : `page-break-inside: avoid;`